# Looking for a function like "directory" that will return directories not files in Common Lisp

Tags: directory, common-lisp

I have used the handy function directory in the past to find a list a list of files at a give path something like this:

(make-pathname :directory "some/path" :name :wild :type :wild)

but as far as I can tell from the documentation and my experimentation this function will only return files and never directories.  Is there a similar function in standard common lisp that will return directories as well?  Does directory in-fact do this and I just missed something?  I am using the Clozure CCL implementation of common lisp.

Comment: Mike, does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282089/listing-directories-in-clisp) help you any?

Comment: Thanks for the link but it seems that this may be different between implementations.  I tried: (directory "/Users/mike/*/") (my home dir is "/Users/Mike") and this returned nothing, of course (directory "/Users/mike/*") or (directory "/Users/mike/*.*") returned lots of files.  Also, (NCONC (DIRECTORY "*/") (DIRECTORY "*")) seemed to return a very incomplete list of files and some subdirectories of subdirectories (according to the docs it should not return subdirectories of subdirectories at all) and returned no direct subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, CCL has its own directory method that has a key argument :directories which if set to true will show subdirectories.  I was just looking at the wrong documentation.  DOH!